# Given the velocity and $\psi(0, t)$ of a wave how do I find $\psi(x, 0)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

I think the title is pretty self explanatory: If $\psi(x, t)$ is an unknown wavefunction of a wave traveling at a known speed $v$, how does one find $\psi(x, 0)$ given $\psi(0, t)$? I know that $\psi(x, t) = f(x - vt)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\psi(x, t) = f(x-vt)$, then $\psi(0,t) = f(-vt)$, whereas
$\psi(x,0) = f(x)$. Consequently $\psi(0,t)$ and $\psi(x,0)$ take the same value when $x=-vt$, that is,
$$\psi(x, 0) = \psi\left(0, -\frac{x}{v}\right)\;.$$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your wave is a solution to the classical wave equation,

$$
\partial_t^2\psi -v^2\partial_x^2\psi=0,
$$

there is a straightforward proof whose details I forget that all solutions are actually one-dimensional functions, $\psi(x,t)=f(x- vt)$.
(I'm ignoring the backward-going waves $f(x+vt)$.)

In that special case, knowledge of the behavior at the origin for all times, $\psi(0,t)=f(-vt)$, can be trivially switched around to give the initial condition of the wave everywhere, $f(x)=\psi(x,0)$.

Comment: I actually knew the $\psi = f(x - vt)$ part and the part that you're calling trivial is what I'm confused by.